# What is the difference between 'git clone user@server/my-repo.git' and 'git clone git://user@server/my-repo.git"

Tags: git

It looks like when I run *git clone user@server/my-repo.git*, it does not use port 9418. Running git clone *git://user@server/my-repo.git* does and fails if the port 9418 is not open.

Which port does the former method use then?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remote+URL+syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clone user@server/my-repo.git` uses ssh protocol with the default port 22. It's equivalent to `git clone ssh://user@server/my-repo.git`.

`git clone git://user@server/my-repo.git` uses git protocol with the default port 9418.

Besides, Git supports http protocol with the default port 80, and https with 443. And for local repositories, `/path/to/repo.git/` and `file:///path/to/repo.git/` are also supported.